# How to globally set custom headers in Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, http-headers, nsurlsession, alamofire

So I have an app that makes frequent requests to various endpoints on our API, and every request pretty much has the same custom headers sent with it. I'd like to know if there is a way to globally set custom header using NSURLSessionConfiguration, and if so...what is the syntax in Swift and where would I put it? AppDelegate? I've done some searching and can't seem to find a good example of this. Is it a bad practice? Not doable?

EDIT:

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for request/response, so I need something that sets them globally so that that library (and others that happen to use NSURLSession) will send the headers along by default.

Comment: well you could create a class and open a public class func which will make requests by type... so you can decide on endpoint, or on type which headers should be added.... Also its a central way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have this documented right in the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0#modifying-session-configuration).

```
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders ?? [:]
defaultHeaders["DNT"] = "1 (Do Not Track Enabled)"

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Then you need to use the new `manager` instead of the global `Alamofire` singleton.

```
manager.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
       .responseJSON { _, _, result in
           debugPrint(result)
       }
```

This will attach the `DNT` header to every request that is sent through this `manager` instance.

> Each `Manager` instance has its own internal `NSURLSession` which also has its own configuration. Therefore, this override only works for this `Manager` instance. If you need these headers on a different `Manager` instance, you'll have to set it up the same way.

Comment: And where would you set this up? Please forgive my ignorance...But this still isn't really setting a global default custom header right? I'm still new to iOS development so some of the best practices are still a bit foreign to me.

Comment: You can only set a global header per session. That's as global as you can get. This isn't a limitation by Alamofire, but a limitation from Apple. As to where to set this up, something like a `NetworkManager` singleton that exposes this `manager` object along with any other ones that you need would do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Good to know.